# JavaScript redirect while passing on the parameter to new URL

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to write the code for a javascript that will redirect to a new url while fetching the url parameter and passing it to the new url.

The visited url = [www.example.com/files/?id=12345](http://www.example.com/files/?id=12345)

New Url to redirect to = [www.sample.com/files/?list=12345](http://www.sample.com/files/?list=12345)

This is the below code i have been able to come up with.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const id = urlParams.get('id');

window.location.href = `www.sample.com/files/?list=${id}`;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to include the scheme

Comment: @DanielA.White Can you help me with the code to do that? Im stucked!

Comment: You're missing the URI scheme in your new URL, ie `https://`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code works well, but when using window.location.href to redirect, the browser by default asumes that the url you are using is relative to the current site, so if you redirect to "sample.com" you are going to end up in "example.com/sample.com"

So to force the browser to redirect to another site you need to include the full URL with the protocol "https://sample.com"

So the fixed code would be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const id = urlParams.get('id');

window.location.href = `https://www.sample.com/files/?list=${id}`;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Note that Im using https, if your site does not have https, change it for http or you are gonna get an error from the browser (and try to get https jeje)

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved!

Comment: Glad to hear that, If your problem was solved you can mark this as the right answer with the green check at the left of the answer